# Clicking a button will put a value at input field without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want to ask on how to put a value in an input field without reloading the page. Heres my code. What i want to happen is that when i click the button, "1234567" will automatically be inside or value of the input fields but without refreshing the page. This how my code is but nothing is happening. Thank you in advance!

**This is for my input fields**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="password">{{ $edit ? trans("app.new_password") : trans('app.password') }} <text class="text-danger">*</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" @if ($edit) placeholder="@lang('app.leave_blank_if_you_dont_want_to_change')" @endif>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="password_confirmation">{{ $edit ? trans("app.confirm_new_password") : trans('app.confirm_password') }} <text class="text-danger">*</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation" @if ($edit) placeholder="@lang('app.leave_blank_if_you_dont_want_to_change')" @endif>
</div>
```

**Then this for my button that when click it will trigger the event**

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm btn-block" id="default_pass" onclick="myFunction()">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></i> Default Pass
</input>
```

**Then this is the javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('click', 'default_pass', function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("password").value = "1234567";
    document.getElementById("password_confirmation").value = "1234567";
  });
</script>
```

PS Im really no good at javascript. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `default_pass` should be `#default_pass`. `#` prefix means to look for an `id`.

Comment: it still doesn't work when i click it nothings happening

Comment: `<input>` isn't a container element, you can't have contents and `</input>`.

Comment: You should use `<button>` instead of `<input type="button">`

Comment: But it does now is submit, so im refreshing the page. I dont want to refresh the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your HTML is invalid. `<input>` isn't a container, so `Default Pass` is not inside it. Clicking on that doesn't trigger a click on the button.

You should use `<button>` instead.

And in the jQuery you need to use `#default_pass` as the selector. You don't need the `onclick` attribute in the button, since you're using jQuery to bind the event handler. You never defined the function as a global name; using `function myFunction()` in the jQuery event handler only defines the name in the local scope of the function; see [Why JavaScript function declaration (and expression)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667148/why-javascript-function-declaration-and-expression)

```js
$(document).on('click', '#default_pass', function myFunction() {
  $("#password, #password_confirmation").val("1234567");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="password">Password <text class="text-danger">*</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" @if ($edit) placeholder="Leave blank if you don't want to change" @endif>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="password_confirmation">Confirm Password <text class="text-danger">*</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation" @if ($edit) placeholder="Leave blank if you don't want to change" @endif>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm btn-block" id="default_pass" >
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></i>                
    Default Pass
</button>
```

Comment: It still doesn't put values at the input field

Comment: It still doesn't put values in the input fields @Barmar